# C Drive is not showing when running powershell command remotely

Tags: powershell

I have prepared a script which will be invoked on remote server and check for the used space threshold. If I run the same script locally, It is giving me the proper output which has C: but from remote It is not showing C:\ and showing the other drives. Here is my script.

```
$th = 50
foreach($v in Get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk -filter 'drivetype = 3')
 {
    Try
    {
    $res=""
            if((( $v.Size - $v.FreeSpace ) / $v.Size )*100 -gt $th)
            { 
                $res = $res+$v.DeviceID+" "+ "{0:N2}" -f ((( $v.Size - $v.FreeSpace ) / $v.Size )*100)
                $res
            }
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        write-host ''
    }
 }
```

Please help me to troubleshoot.

Comment: Works for me. Are you executing the script on the same target machine? I mean: are you sure the threshold condition is met on the target machine when you execute remotely?

Comment: Thanks David. Threshold condition is met for that particular machine. But If I run in my machine, It s working fine but in remote server , It is simply omitting C Drive.